# Why am I getting a 503 from the Amedeus airport API?

Tags: amadeus

I am using the Amadeus Python 3 client, and I get a 503 when calling the method `

```
response =  amadeus.reference_data.locations.airports.get(
    longitude=long,
    latitude=lat)
```

`

Stack trace: `

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/amadeus/reference_data/locations/_airports.py", line 25, in get
    return self.client.get(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/amadeus/mixins/http.py", line 40, in get
    return self.request('GET', path, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/amadeus/mixins/http.py", line 110, in request
    return self._unauthenticated_request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/amadeus/mixins/http.py", line 126, in _unauthenticated_request
    return self.__execute(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/amadeus/mixins/http.py", line 152, in __execute
    response._detect_error(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/amadeus/mixins/parser.py", line 16, in _detect_error
    self.__raise_error(error, client)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/amadeus/mixins/parser.py", line 67, in __raise_error
    raise error
amadeus.client.errors.ServerError: [503]
```

`

Is the API down at the moment?

Comment: Formatting issues

Answer (score 2):

a 503 is a server error. If the api has a status page, check that. If not, reach out to whoever runs it if that is known.    Other than that, only those with access to the servers can tell you why.